# Does two IPs get the same port?

Tags: unix, process, ip, port

if I have machine with more than one IP (related to the same process), will they get the same port? the port is per machine or IP?

Comment: Put the question on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking 3 things in one question, so lets begin by clearing things up a little... (I'm over simplifying it for you)

IP - Internet Protocol (IP) is like a telephone number for the computer. If the computer. Each number is generated from the Ethernet card (NIC) installed in the computer. This means The number of IPs your computer has depends on the number of NICs installed.

Port - The port list is a directory of extensions to the given number (IP). Each port number relates to a specific connect (such as CD driver, or a given software). A single port (ie computer) usually has **MANY** ports open at once.

Process - Processes are execution instances of a program.

Now, to answer your question. The same port (ie) extension could be on 2 different IPs, but 2 different IPs cannot be on a single port. In addition each process has only 1 IP and 1 Port; processes cannot repeat.